# Check number of elements in a channel

Tags: kotlin

I have created an unbounded channel in Kotlin. Is there a way to check how many elements are present in the channel either at receiver or producer side in O(1) ?

Comment: Might count be the one you're looking for? https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/count.html

Comment: I don't think so. Channels (and flows) don't provide such API without collecting the elements.